# Filter input/htmlentities is necessary when using prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql

When i'm using prepared statements...

1 - Should i use filter inputs? (eg. validade int/sanitize strings)
2 - Should i use htmlentities() when outputing the data from database?

Or filter input still increase the security for the web online application?

Thank you.

Comment: Always make sure the data you receive is what you expect it to be. Id you are going to output it somewhere, always assume it is dangerous and sanitize it accordingly.

Comment: None of the things you've mentioned have anything to do with prepared statements. You might need to use them, you might not. It depends on other circumstances than whether you use prepared statements or not

Answer (score 2):

You should always check input to make sure it conforms to the expected format.  Even if you're putting it into prepared statements.

IMHO, data that is IN the database should appear exactly as it is meant to be, and that would mean /without/ HTML entities such as `&amp;` in it.  Let the developer who is outputting the data decide how to format it for that interface.

Yes, you need to use htmlentities() when outputting data to a web page unless you're sure it doesn't have any, erhm, HTML entities.

Answer (score 1):

Reiterating what John Conde said. Assume all data is unsafe and requires sanitation.

The direction of the sanitation may change (e.g., before insert into a database vs. reading from a database)

If you assume you are only inputting data into your database that has been sanitized and sanity checked then you should be able to safely read said data without requiring additional filtering.